# WebKit WebView paste: fails for dynamic UTIs

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, webview

When copying a URL from chrome on OSX and pasting into an editable WebKit webview, nothing gets pasted.

I verified that there are items on the NSPasteboard and that the NSPasteboardItem has the following types:

```
"dyn.ah62d4rv4gu8zs3pcnzme2641rf4guzdmsv0gn64uqm10c6xenv61a3k",
"dyn.ah62d4rv4gu8yc6durvwwaznwmuuha2pxsvw0e55bsmwca7d3sbwu",
"public.utf8-plain-text",
"dyn.ah62d4rv4gu8yg55wqzkgc65yqzvg82pwqvdg22p0r73fk8puqyuda8b1gy5xerwdgk2a",
"dyn.ah62d4rv4gu8yg55wqzkgc65yqzvg82pwqvdg22p0r73fk8puqyuda8b1gy5xerwdg3cu"
```

I understand that these are auto-generated and map to WebURLsWithTitlesPboardType.

On performing the same operation from safari to webview, it works since it only contains

```
"public.utf8-plain-text"
```

Is there a known workaround for handling these UTIs better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Webkit webviews don't seem to support paste operations for dynamic UTIs. I worked around it by recreating the pasteboard items without those UTIs when a paste: was intercepted in webview:doCommandBySelector:

```
- (void)cleanupPasteboard:(NSPasteboard *)pasteboard {
    NSMutableArray *newItems = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for (NSPasteboardItem *item in pasteboard.pasteboardItems) {
        NSPasteboardItem *newItem = [[NSPasteboardItem alloc] init];
        for (NSString *type in item.types) {
            if (![type hasPrefix:@"dyn"]) {
                [newItem setData:[item dataForType:type] forType:type];
            }
        }
        [newItems addObject:newItem];
    }
    [pasteboard clearContents];
    [pasteboard writeObjects:newItems];
}
```